# When writing a recursive function, when to pass 'count' as argument from one recursive call to another vs. defining "count += recursive function"?

Tags: python, recursion

I have written/seen a number of `recursive functions`. My question is that in many questions, we are often asked to keep a `'count'` of something, e.g. "*Count the number of leaf nodes in a binary tree*".

One recursive function would be:

```
def countLeavesInTree(root, count= 0): 
    if root.left: 
        countLeavesInTree(root.left, count)
    if root.right: 
        countLeavesInTree(root.right, count)
    if not root.left and not root.right: 
        count += 1
        return        #How can we increment count by 1 here?- is this right?

    return count
```

Equivalently to the above, I have seen recursions incrementing `'count'` as follows:

```
def countLeavesInTree(root): 
    count = 0 

    if root.left: 
        count += countLeavesInTree(root.left)
        return
    if root.right: 
        count += countLeavesInTree(root.right)
        return
    if not root.left and not root.right: 
        return 1    
    
    return count
```

When do we use the first approach and when do we use the second? Or does it not matter and both can be used in any cases?

**Amended code:**

```
def countLeavesInTree(root):
    count = 0

    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return 1

    else:
        count += countLeavesInTree(root.left) + countLeavesInTree(root.right)

    return count
```

Comment: you can't use the first approach. count is a scoped variable there and will be lost when the function terminates. the second approach is what you will be using most of the time (if you fix your errors that is), but an alternative is to have count as a global parameter and not pass it at all or pass a MUTABLE like a list or a dict

Comment: Both approaches are just broken. The first will either return ``count`` unchanged or ``None``, the second will fail with a name error in 2 out of 3 cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I've added a definition for count to the second approach. @Nullman understood around initialising `count` as a global parameter, but WHY does passing a list or dict work but not a count? And how would I pass a list or dictionary??- in the same way I have done above with count?

Comment: Are you aware that integers are immutable?

Comment: Yes, okay then I understood the fact that we could use 'count' as a store wrongly! Because with a for loop, you can increment count right?- so I assumed it worked in a similar fashion. But I am still struggling with how to amend the second approach?- If I initialise count as a global variable, how can I increment it with each recursive call that is a leaf node??

Comment: The easiest way to see what's happening at each step is to add `print` statements.  The important thing to remember when writing recursive functions is what each call to the function does -- in this case, count all the leaves *under and including this node*, which you can express as "one if this node is a leaf, otherwise the number of leaves under the left node plus the number under the right node".  If that concept doesn't make sense, draw some trees on a piece of paper and it will.  Once the *concept* makes sense, all you need to do is write the code that matches the concept.

Comment: Also, don't even think about doing the whole thing with a global variable IMO.  It's a bad pattern that you'd never want to use in "real life" and dedicating mental energy to it now is just going to hinder you understanding the concept that's actually useful here.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and forget about the possibility of using ``global`` to pass state between recursive calls. Many recursive patterns are *functional* (meaning they rely on producing the same output for the same input) which is next to impossible with ``global``.

Comment: As a sense check- the above code under AMENDED CODE- this is correct now? As it seems to work when I trace it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "amended code" is very close, the only thing you need to add is the guard back to make sure you are not passing a `None` as a new `root`.

You want:

```
def countLeavesInTree(root):
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return 1

    count = 0

    if root.left:
        count += countLeavesInTree(root.left)

    if root.right:
        count += countLeavesInTree(root.right)

    return count
```

or via a comprehension you might:

```
def countLeavesInTree(root):
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return 1

    return sum(
        countLeavesInTree(child)
        for child
        in [root.left, root.right]
        if child
    )
```

a full simple example might be:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = val

root = Node("root")
root.left = Node("root.left")
root.left.left = Node("root.left.left") # a leaf
root.right = Node("root.right")
root.right.right = Node("root.right.right") # a leaf
root.right.left = Node("root.right.left") # a leaf

def countLeavesInTree(root):
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return 1
    return sum(countLeavesInTree(child) for child in [root.left, root.right] if child)

print(countLeavesInTree(root))
```

With luck, that should give you `3`.

You really never want to try to maintain a global like the first version while doing recursion. Python recursion is not great (in that you can unexpectedly reach the default limit rather quickly) so if you wanted to try to maintain a variable like that, it might be better to try to shift out of recursion to a more traditional looping structure.

Perhaps something like:

```
def countLeavesInTree2(root):
    if not root:
        return 0

    count = 0
    brush_pile = [root]
    while brush_pile:
        current = brush_pile.pop(0)
        if not current.left and not current.right:
            count += 1
        else:
            brush_pile.extend(
                child
                for child
                in [current.left, current.right]
                if child
            )
    return count
```

Comment: Thanks so much JonSG, the above makes perfect sense. And I now see your point about guarding back- to check first that a right and left child exist first. Can I ask- was it wrong for me to set `count = 0` before the `base case?` I am assuming this is wrong, as we will hit it in every recursion call and reset count to 0 unintentionally?

Comment: There was nothing technically wrong with setting count to 0 at the start of the function call as if it was a leaf node you were correctly returning 1 anyways. I moved it down a bit to tidy things up as it was technically not needed until after determining the current node is not a leaf.

Comment: One important thing about `count` in the recursive versions above is that it is `not` a global variable. it is local to the "current" execution of the function, though it does take it's current value from the returned values of all child nodes. So setting it to 0 is fine **before** adding the recursive returns of all children,

Comment: Thanks Jon, I do see this now! Initially I thought it would be reset to 0 every time we have a recursive function, but I see now this is not the case- because as you said it is a local variable; and for all the prior recursive call we would have passed count = 0 already! So it doesn't get executed as we add the children 1's back upwards.